# Disable autorun external devices with VLC in kde

Tags: kde, vlc, filemanager, autorun

In installed kubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu 18.04 to use KDE Plasma.

Whenever I select an external device in the left to open it in dolphin, it opens VLC instead and tries to play all files on that disk. This usually crashes VLC and I don't want to play them anyway.

How do I disable this autostart feature of KDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

vlc was registered as default file manager in my system in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

see: https://superuser.com/questions/465495/how-to-find-the-default-file-manager

replace the line with (for example) dolphin:

```
sed 's|inode/directory=vlc.desktop;|inode/directory=dolphin.desktop;|g' ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Then log out and in again.

*This worked for me, I am curious, how this could happen. I installed Ubuntu 17.10 updated to 18.04 and later installed `kubuntu-desktop`.
In that process this bug must have happened. I couldn't find anyone else with this bug.*